# WordPress Custom Taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, taxonomy

I'm wondering if there's a way to list all custom taxonomies that are siblings to the current page (e.g. in my single.php)?

For example my taxonomy is as follows

Categories

- -- Ancient
- +++ Greek
- ///// Plato
- ///// Socrates
- +++ Roman
- +++ Indian
- -- Classic
- -- Modern

I'd like to create a sidebar that lists all other items that have the same parent (including descendants of other siblings - e.g. "Greek" page would list "Roman" and "Indian". The "Ancient" page would include links to "Ancient >> Greek", "Ancient >> Roman", "Ancient >> Indian", "Classic" and "Modern" Pages. )

Is this possible with custom taxonomies? How can I achieve it?

Thanks!

****EDIT****

Also, for reference, I am working with the following blog posts which give a more detailed insight into what I need, I simply am having trouble customizing it to the specifications I mentioned in my original post:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/

https://github.com/scribu/wp-query-multiple-taxonomies/wiki/Changing-templates

http://scribu.net/wordpress/extending-the-category-walker.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post = get_post($id); //Get the post id

    if($post->post_parent){ //If it has a parent

        wp_list_pages('child_of='.$post->post_parent . '&exclude='.$id); //List the pages that are children of the parent page, excluding the current one.

    }
```

This will create a list of all the siblings of a page. I have a feeling you want something slightly different, as you mention custom taxonomies as well as pages. Are these custom post types, categories, or pages? Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks a million Michael!  What I'm looking for is a listing of siblings within the "custom taxonomy" structure, which is different than pages / category, though the hierarchy uses a similar WordPress mechanic, the actual code would be different.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, for reference, I am working with the following blog posts which give a more detailed insight into what I need, I simply am having trouble customizing it to the specifications I mentioned in my original post: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/, https://github.com/scribu/wp-query-multiple-taxonomies/wiki/Changing-templates  , http://scribu.net/wordpress/extending-the-category-walker.html